# Open a link in the same page by using JS

Tags: javascript, jquery

How do I display the content result from "#output" within the same page?

```
<body>
 <script   
 src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js">  
</script>
 <h1>Get Bing Search Feed</h1>
 <input id="keyword" placeholder="Bing Keyword">
 <button id="submit">Get Bing Search RSS Feed</button>
 <a href="#" style="margin-top: 3rem; display: block;" id="output"></a>
 <script type="text/javascript"> 
  $('#submit').click(function() {
    if ($('#keyword').val() != '') {
    alert('For demonstration purposes only. Please do not point your RSS 
 reader to this server.');
    var keyword = $('#keyword').val();

  $('#output').html('').append('https://www.bing.com/search?q=' + keyword +  
'&format=rss').attr('href', 'https://www.bing.com/search?q=' + keyword +   
'&format=rss');
}
});
</script>
</body>
```

I was using below JS to generate the output, but it seems not working. Please Help.

```
<a href="#" onclick="document.getElementById('contents1').style.cssText =   
''">output</a>

<div id="contents1" style="display:none;">
    <h2>Result</h2>
    <iframe src="output.html" width="500" height="400"></iframe>
</div>
```

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/fs3dq747/ i tried your code in fiddle things are qoeking the qhat else you expectation please elaboratein more details

Comment: what is qoeking? I will need the content result in the same page after click the link. In this case, bing search will generate the output when the user enters their keyword, and I want the content showing in the same page after user clicks the link.